Deploy the same contract multiple times with different constructor arguments in Hardhat using Ignition
I am trying to deploy the same smart contract multiple times using Hardhat's Ignition plugin, but with different constructor arguments.
It seems like Ignition performs a reconciliation check and prevents redeployment if the constructor arguments change. I would like to disable this check and deploy the same contract multiple times with different constructor arguments.
Here’s what my current deployment script looks like:
// ignition deployment module
export const RouterModule = buildModule("RouterModule", (m) => {
  const selector = m.getParameter("selector");

  const routerContract = m.contract("Router", [
    selector,
  ]);

  return { routerContract };
});

Deployment script with the specific selector value looks like this
  import { RouterModule } from "../ignition/modules/RouterContracts";

  const { routerContract } = await hre.ignition.deploy(RouterModule, {
    parameters: {
      RouterModule: {
        selector: 1001n,
      },
    },
  });
const routerAddress = await routerContract.getAddress();

When I attempt to redeploy the contract with different selector value, I encounter the following error:
HardhatPluginError: The deployment wasn't run because of the following reconciliation errors:
* RouterModule#Router: Argument at index 0 has been changed

What I want to achieve:

Deploy the same contract (RouterModule) multiple times, each time with different constructor arguments (selector).
Avoid reconciliation checks or force the deployment of a new contract instance even when the constructor arguments change.

I tried the the deploy method with differnt deploymentId, but did not help
